# Unplayable video after running FFmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55332539/5550161) last year. I resolved the issue I had and I implemented the same logic for merging an image with a video, instead of two images. This is running on Android.

Here is the command I'm using currently:

```
"-i", mFilePath, "-i", drawingPath, "-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad='max(iw\\,2*trunc(ih*47/80/2))':'max(ih\\,2*trunc(ow*80/47/2))':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-r", outputFPS, outputPath}
```

`47/80/2` is calculated by getting a device's screen dimensions - `1128 x 1920`.

When running this on certain devices, it results in an unplayable video.

But running the following command works perfectly fine:

```
"-i", mFilePath, "-crf", "18", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", outputPath};
```

I think the issue is with the filter being applied?

---

I compared running the first command on two different devices.

- On the first device (Samsung J7 Pro), I was able to run the command successfully and play the video afterward. I tested the output on both devices and it is working.
- On the second device (Sony Xperia Tablet Z), I was able to run the command successfully but could not play the video. I tested the output on both devices and it doesn't play on either. It does play on my computer.

I compared the original video with the one not working and the one without a filter and the only difference I could find is that the one that is not working profile is `Baseline@L4.2` and the one without a filter profile is `Baseline@L4.0`. The original video profile is `High@L4.0`.

[Here are all the videos](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WdAIXyzNNIIjwsIZWfqRk2DJAJ4zGgh2). The original, the one without a filter (working) and the one with the filter(no working).

I have no idea why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit 1:**

Here is the actual log as requested:

```
"-i", "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/CameraTemp/2020_05_24_09_17_53.mp4", "-i", "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/MyVideos/tempShapes.png", "-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad='max(iw\\,2*trunc(ih*47/80/2))':'max(ih\\,2*trunc(ow*80/47/2))':(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref[v1][v0];[v0][v1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-r", "30", "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/MyVideos/video with line.mp4"
```

and here is the complete log:

```
ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/CameraTemp/2020_05_24_09_17_53.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2020-05-24T08:18:02.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:01.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 20750 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 18056 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.70 fps, 29.67 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-05-24T08:18:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 155 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-05-24T08:18:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/MyVideos/tempShapes.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x1128, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale2ref:default (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 4.2
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] 264 - core 152 r2851M ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=2 keyint_min=1 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/MyVideos/video with line.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1128 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:47], q=-1--1, 29 fps, 14848 tbn, 29 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-05-24T08:18:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
frame=    1 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=0.397x    
frame=    5 fps=1.6 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=0.33x    
frame=    9 fps=2.5 q=24.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=2075.0kbits/s speed=0.28x    
frame=   13 fps=3.1 q=25.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=8298.9kbits/s speed=0.243x    
frame=   18 fps=3.8 q=29.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=16597.5kbits/s speed=0.214x    
frame=   21 fps=3.9 q=25.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=20746.7kbits/s speed=0.19x    
frame=   23 fps=3.9 q=25.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=22821.4kbits/s speed=0.173x    
frame=   26 fps=4.0 q=29.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=29045.3kbits/s speed=0.156x    
Past duration 0.617577 too large
Past duration 0.639641 too large
frame=   28 fps=3.9 q=29.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=31119.9kbits/s speed=0.142x    
Past duration 0.665230 too large
frame=   29 fps=3.8 q=25.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=31119.9kbits/s speed=0.132x    
Past duration 0.690834 too large
Past duration 0.711281 too large
Past duration 0.736885 too large
frame=   32 fps=3.9 q=29.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=37343.8kbits/s speed=0.123x    
Past duration 0.762474 too large
Past duration 0.783577 too large
Past duration 0.807564 too large
frame=   35 fps=3.9 q=25.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=39418.4kbits/s speed=0.112x    
Past duration 0.831551 too large
Past duration 0.855537 too large
frame=   37 fps=3.5 q=25.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=43567.7kbits/s speed=0.0968x    
Past duration 0.879524 too large
Past duration 0.903511 too large
frame=   39 fps=3.4 q=25.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:01.06 bitrate=41196.6kbits/s speed=0.0927x    
Past duration 0.927498 too large
Past duration 0.951500 too large
frame=   41 fps=3.4 q=25.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:01.13 bitrate=38700.0kbits/s speed=0.0931x    
frame=   41 fps=3.2 q=25.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:01.13 bitrate=38700.0kbits/s speed=0.0886x    
frame=   41 fps=3.1 q=25.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:01.43 bitrate=33554.2kbits/s speed=0.108x    
Past duration 0.975487 too large
frame=   45 fps=3.2 q=26.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:01.60 bitrate=33905.4kbits/s speed=0.114x    
frame=   45 fps=3.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    8158kB time=00:00:01.65 bitrate=40480.7kbits/s speed=0.11x    
video:8127kB audio:28kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.032895%
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] frame I:23    Avg QP:24.70  size:337646
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] frame P:22    Avg QP:29.00  size: 25250
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 43.6%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:56.0%
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 90.0% 84.7% 58.1% inter: 20.1% 6.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 25% 28% 28% 20%
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 39% 25% 20% 16%
[libx264 @ 0xb83fc8a0] kb/s:42901.20
[aac @ 0xb83d7d10] Qavg: 3517.779
```

Comment: Show the actual command being executed with real values instead of variables and include the complete log from the same command.

Comment: @llogan Please see Edit1. Sorry, it took some time to get the log from the user.

Comment: Does the following command also produce an unplayable output? `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1.64:r=30:s=1920x1128 -f lavfi -i sine=r=48000 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -ac 2 -shortest output.mp4`

Comment: @llogan Yes, I tested it on multiple Android devices and all of them produce an unplayable output. EDIT - I changed `1920x1128` to the actual device dimensions `1920x1080`, then it works.

Comment: I guess the device refuses to play anything over level 4.0. 1920x1128 will exceed level 4.0. You're probably stuck with 1920x1080 or lower.

Comment: @llogan I suspected that would be the case. Is there a way that I can, instead of adding padding, rather center crop the sides of the image that is being overlayed on top of the video? I should probably ask a new question for this..?

Comment: Sure, make a new question. I added an answer specific to this existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess these devices refuse to play anything over level 4.0. 1920x1128 will exceed level 4.0. Setting `-level` won't help because it will still exceed the level and you'll get a warning similar to `frame MB size (120x69) > level limit (8192)`.

Detailed specifications regarding playback support are often hard to find, if they are available at all, but [Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/SM-J730GZKWINS/) only states that the Galaxy J7 Pro "Video Playing Resolution: FHD (1920 x 1080)@60fps". I didn't check the Sony Xperia Tablet Z, but since it is from 2012 I wouldn't doubt it is in a similar situation.

This wasn't the answer you were looking for, but **you may be limited to 1920x1080 or lower**. Of course I may be wrong. Make sure you're using the latest available OS version and refer the device specs if you can find something more detailed and informative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try forcing the level to 4.0 with the `-level 4.0` option.

Try

```
ffmpeg ... -profile:v baseline -level:v 4.0 ...
```